# Jetpack compose error while compiling the code with SDK migration 34 and jetpack compose v = 1.5.4

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I recently migrated to sdk 34 from 33 and I am not able to compile the code.

Error generated code:

```
  composable(
        route = route,
        arguments = arguments,
        deepLinks = deepLinkList(route),
        enterTransition = { enterTransition() },
        popEnterTransition = { popEnterTransition() },
        popExitTransition = { popExitTransition() },
        exitTransition = { exitTransition() }
    ) {
```

error log:

```
File being compiled: (273,29) in /Users/.../NavGraph.kt
The root cause org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ErrorExpressionException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ErrorExpressionGenerator.generateErrorCall(ErrorExpressionGenerator.kt:100)
null: KtCallExpression:
enterTransition()
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:253)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException$default(CodegenUtil.kt:237)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.DeclarationGenerator.generateMemberDeclaration(DeclarationGenerator.kt:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ModuleGenerator.generateSingleFile(ModuleGenerator.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ModuleGenerator.generateModuleFragment(ModuleGenerator.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:255)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.convertToIr(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:224)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:460)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.doCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:476)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:399)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileNonIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:280)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:636)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1598)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ErrorExpressionException: null: KtCallExpression:
enterTransition()
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ErrorExpressionGenerator.generateErrorCall(ErrorExpressionGenerator.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitCallExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:390)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitCallExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression.accept(KtCallExpression.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatement(StatementGenerator.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.BodyGenerator.generateLambdaBody(BodyGenerator.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.FunctionGenerator.generateLambdaFunctionDeclaration(FunctionGenerator.kt:66)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.LocalFunctionGenerator.generateLambda(LocalFunctionGenerator.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitLambdaExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:531)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitLambdaExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtLambdaExpression.accept(KtLambdaExpression.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatement(StatementGenerator.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt$pregenerateCall$1.invoke(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:508)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt$pregenerateCall$1.invoke(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:508)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.generateValueArgumentUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:371)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateValueArgumentsUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:755)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateCallUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:518)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateCall(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:508)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitCallExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:409)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitCallExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression.accept(KtCallExpression.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatement(StatementGenerator.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatements(StatementGenerator.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.BodyGenerator.generateFunctionBody(BodyGenerator.kt:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.FunctionGenerator.generateFunctionDeclaration(FunctionGenerator.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.FunctionGenerator.generateFunctionDeclaration$default(FunctionGenerator.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.DeclarationGenerator.generateMemberDeclaration(DeclarationGenerator.kt:49)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: You can't use a method with the same name as a named parameter like that - have you tried renaming your `enterTransition()` method to something else?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes I did and it doesn't work, same error

Comment: I found the problem, it was because of the composable was imported from Accompanist api now its imported from stable navigation api and works fine